# Xamarin.Android debug builds failing in VisualStudio 2015 after Xamarin update

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, xamarin.android

Using VisualStudio 2015 update 2 for a Xamarin app solution with Xamarin.Forms (PCL), Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.iOS projects.

After upgrading Xamarin.Forms from 2.1.0.6529 to 2.2.0.31 today, debug builds of the Xamarin.Android app within VisualStudio started consistently failing with the following message:

```
Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1853,3): error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -jar
```

I am certainly open to the suggestion to increase `$(JavaMaximumHeapSize)`, and it looks like an MSBuild property by the `$()` syntax, but I'm not certain where I would set this.

How or where is the `JavaMaximumHeapSize` specified for Xamarin.Android builds in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found [this thread on Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2132/java-heap-space-outofmemoryerror-when-binding-a-big-jar) that indicates the `JavaMaximumHeapSize` property can be added to the Xamarin.Android project's csproj file.

Looked at the csproj file with text editor, and found the `JavaMaximumHeapSize` element already existed in the first `PropertyGroup`, but there was no value in the element.

So I put `1G` in as a value, and the Xamarin.Android project began building successfully once again:

```
<JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
```

Hope this saves someone else a bit of searching.

Comment: Ran into the same issue with the same resolution a while back

Comment: Thanks, that was quick fix!

Answer (score 1):

Yep it worked for me also.  One of my projects already had the stub while the other didn't at all.

I tried putting the limit up to 10G but that seems to struggle and wouldn't build so I changed it back to the 1G as shown.